# discrete finite summation of non-linear functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Does anyone have idea for dealing with the two following series summations

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a+b x_i}=c $$

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{x_i}{a+b x_i}=d $$

I need to find the values of 'a' and 'b'; 'c' and 'd' are known. $x_i$ is discrete variables. I am facing difficulty to do that since the function is non-linear.

I look forward your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check your question, it contains weird characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily reduce this to a one-variable problem.

Note that $$a \; \dfrac{1}{a+b x_i} + b \; \dfrac{x_i}{a + b x_i} = 1$$
Summing from $i=1$ to $n$ we get
$$ a c + b d = n$$
I'll assume $d \ne 0$, so $b = (n - a c)/d$.  With this substitution, your first equation becomes

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{d}{a (d - c x_i) + n x_i} = c \tag{1}$$

You could expand it out, getting a rather awful polynomial of order $n$ in the variable $a$, but this won't likely have a "closed-form" solution anyway.  Probably best is to use numerical methods on (1) directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your thought. I appreciate your suggestion. converting the two variable problem to a single variable problem is an good idea in this case. But solving the equation 1 numerically may also give plenty of solutions. It will depend on the constraints those we can impose. Can you please elaborate which numerical method can I apply to obtain unique solution of 'a' from equation 1

Comment: I don't understand what you asking.  If there are many solutions, there is not a unique solution.  If you wish, you can impose further constraints, e.g. specify that $a$ is in a certain interval, and typically numerical solution methods will be able to look for a solution in that interval.  What I would use is Maple's **fsolve**.  Other CAS's have equivalents.

Comment: I was thinking in a way where I have two sets of random number of size 'n'. Now if I substitute them into the equation 1 then will it give the same answer of 'a'?

Comment: Substitute them for $x_1, \ldots, x_n$?  Why should they give the same answer?  Almost certainly they won't.

Comment: Because 'a' and 'b' are constants. It should not matter whatever set of $x_i$s are there. Here, only $x_i$s are any arbitrary variables. Do you have any idea how do I tract it analytically?

Comment: No, that's wrong.  The left sides of the equations depend on $x_i$.